# InstallShield .NET 4.6.1 Framework installation on Windows 10

Tags: installation, installshield, .net-framework-version

I have Basic MSI project created with InstallShield 2015 that installing .net framework 4.6.1 on WIN 10.
I’m passing **/norestart /q** parameters to NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe and check if the value of **Release** under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full** is less than **394271**.

I have restarted the PC and only then ran the setup, the problem is that when .net 4.6.1 is finished I can see in the log file that installation completed successfully and restart is needed, the value of Release in the registry isn’t updated and therefor I get a message that the installation appears to be failed.

Only after I reboot the machine the registry is being updated.
Any ideas how to solve it ?

Link to html log [.NET 4.6.1 MSI log file](https://ufile.io/gq138)
( After click on link choose Free Download )

Comment: Only after a reboot?  Strange. Can you post the MS log for 4.6.1?

Comment: I also had same issue while performing romote installation of setup which was having .NET prerequisite. I didn't get any resolution for that. I have also raised the concern for the same to MS.